# Python Pokemon Game While Loops

Tags: python

Okay, I'm coding a Pokemon text adventure kind of game and I need help with while loops. I've already created the while loops. But the part that's not working is: you have a choice between choosing two raw_inputs,  run or battle. It won't show the message when you choose either one of those. All it does is repeat the question I programmed it to.

The question asks "Do you want to Run or Battle the Yveltal?" You can either type in "Run" or "Battle" in the iPython session. When you type `Battle`, it's supposed to say "You challenged the Yveltal to a battle!" When you type `Run`, it's supposed to say "You can't run you coward," but if you type anything in, all it does is ask the same question "Do you want to Run or Battle the Yveltal?"

What I want help with is leaving the while loop, and when you type either run or battle, it will show the message for that command. Here's the code, and I could use help from anyone, thank you!

```
from time import sleep
def start():
    sleep(2)
    print "Hello there, what is your name?"
    name = raw_input ()
    print "Oh.. So your name is %s!" % (name)
    sleep(3)
    print"\nWatch out %s a wild Yveltal appeared!" % (name)
    sleep(4)
    user_input = raw_input("Do you want to Run or Battle the Yveltal?" "\n")
    while raw_input() != 'Battle' or user_input == 'battle' != 'Run' or user_input == 'run':
        print("Do you want to Run or Battle the Yveltal? ")
    if user_input == 'Battle' or user_input == 'battle':
        print("You challenged Yveltal to a battle!")
    elif user_input == 'Run' or user_input == 'run':
        print("You can't run you coward!")
```

Comment: So , what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is riddled with errors or mistakes. Try this:

`while user_input.lower() != "battle" or user_input.lower() != "run":`
Using the .lower() function makes so that you don't have to plan for "RuN" or "baTTle". It converts the string to lower case so that you can just check the word. Also, you should use input() instead of raw_input() Honestly I would structure your code like this:

```
user_input = input("Run or battle?\n") #or whatever you want your question
user_input = user_input.lower()
while True:
    if user_input == "battle":
          print("You challenged Yveltal to a battle!")
          break
    elif user_input == "run":
          print("You can't run you coward!")
          user_input = input("Run or battle?\n") 
          user_input = user_input.lower()
          break
    else:
          user_input = input("Run or battle?\n") 
          user_input = user_input.lower()
```

You might have better luck with code like that.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask another favor, but I would like it to ask the "Run or battle" message again if you enter run, if you typed "run" it would say "You can't run you coward" then show the "Run or battle" string everytime you enter run, but this would only be if you entered only "Run", but the rest is really helpful! Also, I used raw_input, because you don't have to type 'run', you could just type run. It also doesn't re-ask the question if you don't answer either "run" or "battle" all it says is it's not defined instead of asking the same question waiting for a valid response.

Comment: input() returns a string. The user can just type the word regularly. Also, did you try this code? It works for me how I understand you want it to.

Comment: In your answer below, the else statement is indented wrong. That's why it won't perform correctly. Indent it one more time and you should be good.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on my machine. Could be your version of python. I'm running 3.5.2. If raw_input() works for you, then go ahead, but I've had more luck with input() in my experience.